# Combination in a unique way

Tags: probability

There are 15 married couple.  I should choose 10 people from them.  The groupe which I choose should include exactly 3 couples.  How many ways can I choose them?

FIrst, I chose 3 couples from 15 couples(combination). And I chose 4 people from the rest(combination), but it was wrong answer

Comment: What ideas came into your mind when you read this exercise ? Please tell us.

Comment: Any thoughts?  How many ways are there to choose the three couples?  What sort of choices must I make from the rest?

Comment: FIrst, I chose 3 couples from 15 couples(combination).  And I chose 7 people from the rest(combination), but it was wrong answer.

Comment: After choosing 3 couples = 6 people in total..You can choose only 4 people

Comment: oh, i mistook to it.  Yes, I chose 4 people but the answer is tottaly different

Comment: You can't choose $4$ people freely from the other $12$ couples....you have to avoid choosing another couple!  thus you first need to choose which couples you will select from, $\binom {12}4$, and then you have to choose one each from each of them.

Comment: Correction:  in my last comment I incorrectly wrote $7$ where I intended $15-3=12$ for the number of couples remaining after you have selected three.

Comment: Why is ${24 \choose 4}$ wrong?  In this case, I do not care whether the rest people are couple or not.

  ${15 \choose 3}$${24 \choose 4}$

Comment: Yes you do.  If you choose a couple in the remaining four then you won't have "exactly three couples".

Comment: ${15 \choose 3}$${12 \choose 4}$$*2*2*2*2$ is the answer.  I am not sure why I can muptiply ${12 \choose 4}$.  This means I choose 4 couples more, right?

Comment: I know what the answer is. And it should be $\binom {12}4$ in the middle there. I'm just trying to explain to you where your reasoning is flawed.

Comment: Sorry, I mistook to enter the key while writing.

Comment: I understand it by your post below.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is:

First choose the three couples that you will select.  there are $\binom {15}3$ ways to do that.

Now you have to choose $4$ people out of the remaining $12$ couples but you can't choose them freely, you have to avoid drawing any more couples.

To do that, first choose the couples your four will be taken from.  there are $\binom {12}4$ ways to do that.  Now I have to choose one person from each of those four couples, there are $2^4$ ways to do that.  Thus the final answer is $$\binom {15}3\times \binom {12}4 \times 2^4$$